# iOS 7 MapKit MKAnnotationView's image property type encoding weirdness

Tags: mapkit, mkannotationview, rubymotion, ios7

These are the results of

```
method_getTypeEncoding(class_getInstanceMethod(MKAnnotationView.class, @selector(setImage:)))
method_getTypeEncoding(class_getInstanceMethod(MKAnnotationView.class, @selector(image)))
```

7.0:

```
v12@0:4^{UIImage=#^vf{?=b1b3b1b1b1b16b2}}8
^{UIImage=#^vf{?=b1b3b1b1b1b16b2}}8@0:4
```

and 6.1:

```
v12@0:4@8
@8@0:4
```

I don't understand why it's a `^{...` instead of `@`. It's causing me problems in [Rubymotion](http://hipbyte.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/RM-211).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using RubyMotion? This looks like Obj-C to me.

Comment: Yeah I'm running those calls in Objective-C. Rubymotion uses these results in .bridgesupport files.

Comment: Ah, got it. You may want to submit a RubyMotion support ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they fixed it in RubyMotion 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Promotion](https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion) and it's [MapKit support](https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion/wiki/API-Reference%3a-ProMotion%3a%3aMapScreen) (that I wrote). It makes it REALLY easy to draw a map screen and put annotations on the map (and customize their look).

https://github.com/clearsightstudio/ProMotion